# PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and somehow got thrown into an advanced level course. My instructor will not offer any help since it is an advanced course. I will post my code below in hopes that someone can at least point me in the right direction for a fix. This is only the first part of the assignment, but not worth going any further if I cannot get this part to work. I believe I have check all the braces and quotes, but I sure could have missed something or ?????.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.error {color: #FF0000;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php
// define variables and set to empty values
$name1Err = $name2Err = $dobErr = $stateErr = $zipErr = "";
$name1 = $name2 = $dob = $state = $zip = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{
   if (empty($_POST["name1"]))
     {$name1Err = "First Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $name1 = test_input($_POST["name1"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name1))
       {
       $name1Err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["name2"]))
     {$name2Err = "Name is required";}
   else
     {
     $name2 = test_input($_POST["name2"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name2))
       {
       $name2Err = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["dob"]))
     {$dobErr = "Date Of Birth is required";}
   else
     {
     $dob = test_input($_POST["dob"]);
     // check if date of birth format is valid
     if (!preg_match("/^[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{1,2}\-[0-9]{4}$/",$dob))
       {
       $dobErr = "Invalid date format";
       }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["state"]))
     {$stateErr = "2 Digit State Abbreviation is required";}
   else
     {
     $state = test_input($_POST["state"]);
     // match two uppercase letters with definite (one or more) whitespace on either side)
     if (!preg_match("/\s+[A-Z]{2}\s+/ ",$state))
       {
       $stateErr = "Invalid State Abbreviation";
   }
     }

   if (empty($_POST["zip"]))
     {$zipErr = "Zip Code is required";}
   else
     {
     $zip = test_input($_POST["zip"]);
     // Validates Zip Code (5 digits plus optional -4)
     if (!preg_match("^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$",$zip))
       {
       $zipErr = "Only letters and white space allowed";
       }
     }


function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
   First Name: 
     <input type="text" name="name1">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $name1Err;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Last Name: 
   <input type="text" name="name2">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $name2Err;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Date Of Birth: 
   <input type="text" name="dob">
   <span class="error"><?php echo $dobErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   State: 
     <input type="text" name="state">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $stateErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   Zip Code: 
   <input type="text" name="zip">
   <span class="error">* <?php echo $zipErr;?></span>
   <br><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name1;
echo "<br>";
echo $name2;
echo "<br>";
echo $dob;
echo "<br>";
echo $state;
echo "<br>";
echo $zip;
?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check your open/close braces in your two code sections, make sure they line up.

Comment: Lesson #1: Pick a consistent style for braces and indentation and stick to it. This minimizes these kinds of errors tremendously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

You are missing to close you `if..` statement.

```
 if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
 {  
    // your code
 }
^^^
```

Use Better Text Editor to get rid from this type of SYNTAX errors